# Azure Failover database not replicating login/user

Tags: azure

I've set up Geo-replication on an Azure Database Server.

One of the databases running on the server has a login and user that I created through SSMS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

I cant connect to the failover database with that user. The user is visible in the replicated database, but the login is not visible in the master db. Moreover, chaning the connection string to point the the replication DNS name doesnt work.

Do I need to create the login manually on the failover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use contained users (those which are stored in the database, not in the masted database), that way you dont need to do anything.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable

Comment: Thanks, removed the Login and created the user according to the article. Can log in with the user both places now. Is it fine to use the server name of the primary server in the connection string of my application; will azure select the failover automatically if primary is down?

Comment: no, i dont think this is how it works, you have to take care of the connection string on your own (but dont quote me on this). also, you should accept this answer ;)

Comment: I know it may not be concered directly to the problem at hand (db not replicating user), however questions are connected to failover and replication. I understood that it works that way at below link. Do you interpret the article differently? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable

Comment: Sorry, here is the correct link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-now-supports-transparent-geographic-failover-of-multiple-databases-featuring-automatic-activation/

Comment: yes, you are correct, i didnt really know that, thanks!